# ¿Qué hacer con preguntas en el limbo de lo bueno y lo malo?

Tags: soporte, colas-de-revisión

Situación típica en revisión: una pregunta que tal cual está merece ser cerrada, pero que puede ser mejorada (con más detalles o aclaraciones).

Normalmente voto por dejarla abierta, en la esperanza de que el OP la mejore, pero ¿qué pasa si el OP nunca la mejora y tampoco alcanza los votos de cierre?

¿Puedo votarla por cerrarla después de un tiempo?

Si alguien más vota después por cerrarla, ¿me aparecerá nuevamente en la cola de revisión?

Si bien puede revisar mis votos en contra/cierre/etc, parece no haber una opción para ver los votos de "Dejar abierta".

No he probado a votar "Dejar abierta" y luego intentar votar por cierre, pues probablemente perjudicaría a algún inocente.

Comment: Si la pregunta vale la pena y puede ser útil a más gente, ¡edítala para hacerla mejor!

Comment: Si votas para dejarla abierta, también deberías editarla para mejorar su calidad. Si no piensas que se pueda mejorar, vota por cerrarla.

Answer (score 4):

Piensa que cerrar una pregunta no es algo permanente: se puede votar por reabrir si hay una edición posterior al cierre. Si la pregunta está falta de contenido y no puedes añadirlo porque es tarea del OP (por ejemplo proveer de un mensaje de error o de más código), entonces vota para cerrar sin miedo. Si el OP la edita, podrá pedir la reapertura posterior.

Es algo que no pasa a menudo porque generalmente las malas preguntas causadas por falta de esfuerzo son cerradas y esa misma dejadez hace que el OP las abandone, lamentablemente; pero eso ya no es responsabilidad nuestra.

Comment: Bien explicado. Yo a veces le doy a cerrar pero me la pongo en favoritos para quitar el voto de cierre si hay cambios.